# SVN accident, overwrote some key changes in my file and committed to repository.  Can it be recovered?

Tags: svn

So sheepishly I ask if this is possible...

In trying to resolve a conflicted file, I overwrote all my changes with the most recent version from the repository and then committed.  Now I'm realizing I wanted to save a lot of that.  Does my local svn keep track of the changes?  Are they at all recoverable?

Comment: You could try with a general undelete utility. If you haven't made any big changes on your filesystem, there is some chance you will get a usable file, or portions of the file.

Comment: Some IDEs have the ability to track a (limited) amount of changes ... you may want to take a look at that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

svn only keeps the changes that you commit, if you never committed the changes then they will of been lost.

How did you resolve the conflict?  There is a small chance that the files that svn creates when it detects a conflict, something like `<filename>.r<revision_number>` will still be there if you resolved the conflict manually.

Comment: This is the best shot, but it probably won't work because "svn resolved" cleans up all those files (as does "svn revert").

Comment: Undelete? * required - at least 15 characters

Comment: Robert - I am not sure what you mean?

Comment: Whenever a file is deleted, it remains on the disk until it is overwritten. There's a small chance that it can be recovered, especially if it was deleted very recently and is a small (i.e. one block) file. Try this app: http://www.piriform.com/recuva

Answer (score 2):

Unless the stuff you wanted was already in the repository I'm afraid you're out of luck. It's gone.

This is a reason to ALWAYS check `svn diff` before you run `svn commit`.

Comment: Checking svn diff output before committing would not have made any difference. The local changes were already lost when he chose the repository version and marked the conflict as resolved. Committing comes after that.

Answer (score 2):

No svn clients I know keep a local history, but some IDEs (e.g. Eclipse do).

Answer (score 1):

I just had the same problem and came across this via Google.  Luckily, a few minutes after that sinking feeling, I checked my Windows recycle bin and had the file with a .mine suffix in there.  I restored that file and got back several days worth of work.

Answer (score 0):

No, the only recoverable data is the one you (or someone else) previously commited.

Sorry!